# How to easily add hours and minutes to gmtime

Tags: c, linux, time.h

Is there a predefined method of addition of hours and minutes to the `gmtime` obtained through `time.h`? I want to write a program to display time for various countries, so do I have to write the logic myself or is there a predefined method?

Comment: like [zdump](http://linux.die.net/man/8/zdump) ? (eg. `zdump US/Eastern`)

Answer (score 3):

There is no standardized function that does the necessary work. However, you can do it relatively simple by modifying your `struct tm`. The struct hold a number of members; one for hours, one for minutes etc. Once you have updated the struct's members your should call `mktime` in order to normalize the values.

For example if the minutes were already set to 55 and you add ten they will then be set to 65. Calling `mktime` will set the minutes to 5 and update the hours and potentially other members accordingly.

As an example adding ten minutes would look like this:

```
struct tm *t = ...
t->tm_min += 10;
mktime(t);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the time zone names (like `Europe/Helsinki` or `US/Eastern` or `MST`), there is a very easy POSIX interface.

It does apply the time zone for the entire process, so if you are using threads, you need to wrap your date/time functions to avoid concurrent date/time accesses unless they use the same time zone, using e.g. mutexes. The examples shown here are not thread-safe, to make the examples easier to understand.

First, set the environment variable `TZ` to the time zone name prefixed by a colon. This is the method used in POSIX systems to set time zone for individual processes (and affects all threads in a process). For example,

```
setenv("TZ", ":Europe/Helsinki", 1);
```

sets the Helsinki timezone. See [`man 3 setenv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html) for details. That alone is not enough; you must also tell the C library to update the current timezone, by calling

```
tzset();
```

You can then examine the global variables `tzname[0]` (which should contain `Europe`) and `tzname[1]` (which should contain `Helsinki`) to see which timezone was actually set. See [`man 3 timezone`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/timezone.3.html) for further details; you can e.g. use the POSIX timezone definition syntax instead to specify custom timezones.

After the two lines above, whenever you use [`localtime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html) or `localtime_r()`, the selected timezone is applied. It's that easy.

---

If you also wish to change the formatting of the timestamp to conform to a specific locale, you can set the locale (say, to `fi_FI.utf8`) via

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fi_FI.utf8");
```

Note, as the [`man 3 setlocale`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html) manpage says, the locale must be in canonical format, short forms like `fi` won't work. Then, using e.g.

```
time_t     now_time;
struct tm *now_tm;
char      *format;
char       buffer[256];
size_t     length;

time(&now_time);
now_tm = localtime(&now_time);
if (!now_tm) {
    /* Error, cannot get local time corresponding to now_time! */
    return -1;
}

format = nl_langinfo(D_T_FMT);
if (!format || !*format) {
    /* Error, cannot get date-time formatting string for this locale */
    return -1;
}

/* Note: both now_tm and format point to static buffers,
 *       and they will be overwritten by subsequent calls.
*/

length = strftime(buffer, sizeof buffer, format, now_tm);
if (length < 1 || length >= sizeof buffer) {
    /* Error in locale configuration; cannot generate date-time string. */
    return -1;
}
```

at which point `buffer` contains the date and time in Finnish (or whatever locale set in the last `setlocale(LC_TIME, locale)` call), in the Finnish timezone (or whatever timezone was set in the last `setenv("TZ", ":Europe/Helsinki", 1); tzset();` call).

(The final `length` check is backwards-compatible to some very old systems, which returned `sizeof buffer` if the buffer was too small. Newer systems return that when the buffer was just large enough, but I'd expect 256 bytes to suffice for time and date in any language.)

I wanted to point this out because in POSIX-like systems, locale (language and formatting) and timezone are completely separate.